# asp FormView delete not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a formview with an insert and a delete button. The insert button fires the onInserting event, but the delete button does not fire the onDeleting event. Why? Here's my code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="LanguagesFormView" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" DataSourceID="LanguageSqlDataSource" OnItemInserting="LanguagesFormView_ItemInserting" OnItemDeleting="LanguagesFormView_ItemDeleting">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LanguageSqlDataSource" ValueField="LanguageID" TextField="LanguageEN"></dx:ASPxComboBox>
        <dx:ASPxListBox ID="ASPxListBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ProjectLanguageSqlDataSource" TextField="LanguageEN"></dx:ASPxListBox>
        <dx:ASPxButton ID="addLangASPxButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Add"></dx:ASPxButton>
        <dx:ASPxButton ID="deleteLangASPxButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></dx:ASPxButton>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

I tested it by placing breakpoints at the event handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OnItemDeleting event doesn't fire while the FormView is in Inserting mode - which makes sense, because how would you know which record to delete if you're just inserting a new one?

If you put the delete button in the ItemTemplate instead of the InsertItemTemplate then the delete event handler will fire correctly.

```
<asp:FormView ID="LanguagesFormView" runat="server" DataSourceID="LanguageSqlDataSource"
    OnItemInserting="LanguagesFormView_ItemInserting" OnItemDeleting="LanguagesFormView_ItemDeleting" DataKeyNames="LanguageID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        ...
        <dx:ASPxButton ID="deleteLangASPxButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Also note that you should set the DataKeyNames property on the FormView in order to get the key you want to delete server-side.

Comment: And what to do if I want to see both the delete and insert buttons at the same time, without having to switch modes?

Comment: Still I'm not sure how you would know which record to delete if you're in insert mode and no existing record is selected. If you absolutely must use your code form above, you can check the Request.Forms collection in Page_Load on postback - if the delete button is clicked, Request.Forms will contain its ID. Still you'd have to find a way to get the ID of the record to delete though.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, the Selectedvalue of ASPxComboBox1 is a Deleteparameter, which is used in the WHERE clause of the Deletecommand.